# Adding Node to End of Linked List in C causes Stack Dump

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

I am working on trying to add a node to the end of a linked list, but I am receiving cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile.

Definition of my Node Struct:

```
struct Node
{
int number;        /* data portion    */
struct Node *next; /* pointer portion */
};
```

Free Memory Function:

```
void free_list(struct Node *list) {
while(list) {
    struct Node *temp = list->next; 
    free(list); 
    list = temp; 
}

}
```

Adding Node to End Function:

```
void add_back(struct Node **list, int value) {
struct Node *node; 
struct Node *temp; 
node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

if(node == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to allocate memory."); 
} else {
    node->number = value; 
    node->next = NULL; 

    temp = *list; 

    while(temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next; 
    }

    temp->next = node; 
}

}
```

And, last but not least, my test case for above function:

```
void test_add_back(void)
{
int i;
struct Node *list = NULL;

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
printf("add %2i to back: ", i);
add_back(&list, i);
print_list(list);
}

free_list(list);
}
```

Opposed to my stack dump, I should be getting:

```
test_add_back ========================================
add  1 to back:   1
add  2 to back:   1  2
add  3 to back:   1  2  3
add  4 to back:   1  2  3  4
add  5 to back:   1  2  3  4  5
add  6 to back:   1  2  3  4  5  6
add  7 to back:   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
add  8 to back:   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
add  9 to back:   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
add 10 to back:   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

In short, I am unsure which piece is causing this stack dump, I feel fairly confident that it is likely an error within my add_back() function but it's also possible that my free_list() function is causing a memory leak.

Anyhow, any help in determining what is causing the stack dump appreciated. 
Cheers, 
Toby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is desirable that after deleting all nodes in the list the pointer that points to the head node was equal to NULL.

So it is better to define the function `free_list` the following way passing the pointer to the head node by reference.

```
void free_list( struct Node **list ) 
{
    while( *list ) 
    {
        struct Node *current = *list;
        *list = ( *list )->next; 
        free( current ); 
    }
}
```

The function `add_back` invokes undefined behavior when it is called for an empty list due to these statements

```
temp = *list; 

while(temp->next != NULL) {
```

because initially `*list` is equal to `NULL`.

The function shall not issue any message. It is the caller of the function that will decide whether to issue a message if any. The function shall report whether a new node was appended successfully by returning an integer value equal to `0` or `1`.

The function can be defined the following way.

```
int add_back( struct Node **list, int value ) 
{
    struct Node *node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = node != NULL; 

    if ( success ) 
    {
        node->number = value; 
        node->next = NULL; 

        while( *list != NULL ) 
        {
            list = &( *list )->next; 
        }

        *list = node; 
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: thanks Vlad! that makes sense now. cheers and hope you are well